# save file to virtual directory

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-directory

Hi I am unsure how to do this, I am using shared hosting. I have a virtual directory at http://www.example.com/images. This directory is actually  a folder on the server  assets/images whereas my site is at /httpdocs (httpdocs and assets folder are at the same level).

How can I save files to this folder and then access using eg /images/foo.jpg?

httpdocs/
--web.config
--default.aspx
--etc

assets/
--images/
----foo.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can save files normally (using `FileStream`s or other things).
Call `Server.MapPath("~/httpdocs")` to get the path on disk.

Comment: so to save to the assets/images dir which is outside the website directory would it be Server.MapPath("~/assest/images/")?

Comment: @raklos: How is it outside the website directory?

Comment: httpdocs and assets are at the same level. so the assets folder sits outside the website. see editted question

Comment: If the virtual was created within httpdocs for "images" (im assuming here that the virtual path would be /httpdocs/images) the path would be Server.MapPath("~/images") in default.aspx. The virtual itself would be set in IIS with the path .../assets/images.

Comment: what if the virtual directory exist on another server?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to create a virtual directory in the IIS Manager so that /images actually points to assets\images (you said you already have a virtual directory on it, so this may already be done). To save things there, you use Server.MapPath("~/images") as SLaks mentioned. Server.MapPath gives you the physical location and you can save to it the way you'd save a file normally.

Exactly how you save it depends on how the person is uploading it. Are you using a form where someone picks a file and then submits it on a web page? If you are, [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/fileupload.aspx) will help you with the saving part.

Good luck. :)